# Show aspects based on data availability

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Some of our products don't have dimensions.

Through functions.php We have managed to add a specific dimension section with height, depth & width on our products pages and now we are wanting to only show these dimensions if there is data available. Some products will have just a height and width others will have no dimensions and some will have all three dimensions.

We want to remove the entire column if the data is not available to be called.
As an example, if the width and depth are available but the height is not available we do not want to show the height heading or the empty cell, however we still want to show the width & depth heading and information.

This is the code in features.php which we call in functions.php:

```html
<table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Width</th>
        <th>Depth</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($product->id, 'height', true); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($product->id, 'width', true); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta($product->id, 'depth', true); ?></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

We pull in the data if it is available through id, 'height', true); ?>

Please see these links for an example of what it currently looks like:

With data available: https://leckys.com.au/product/switch-2g-w-p-15a-250v-2/

With partial data available: https://leckys.com.au/product/socket-swt-twin-w-p-10a-250v/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 <table class="table">
  <tr>
    <?php if(get_post_meta($product->id, "height", true) ): ?><th>Height</th><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_post_meta($product->id, "width", true) ): ?><th>Width</th><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_post_meta($product->id, "depth", true) ): ?><th>Depth</th><?php endif; ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <?php if(get_post_meta($product->id, "height", true) ): ?><td><?php echo get_post_meta($product->id, 'height', true); ?></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_post_meta($product->id, "width", true) ): ?><td><?php echo get_post_meta($product->id, 'width', true); ?></td><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(get_post_meta($product->id, "depth", true) ): ?><td><?php echo get_post_meta($product->id, 'depth', true); ?></td><?php endif; ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, this worked great!